# Passing selected option from drop down in flask

Tags: python, flask, dropdown, dashboard

I am making a dashboard and I want to be able to be able to display graphs for the selected month from .csv files. 
This is my .html page

```
 <form action="/">
<select name = "userinput">
        <option selected>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option >March</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>May</option>
    {% for input in userinput %}
        {% if input == current_userinput %}
            <option selected value= "{{input}}">{{input}}</option>

        {% else %}
            <option selected value = "{{input}}"> {{input}}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
        </select>
</form>
```

This is my app.py

```
@application.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def home():

    current_userinput = request.args.get("userinput")
    if current_userinput == None:
        current_userinput = "February"
    file_path = os.path.join(path_ios, current_userinput+ios)
```

but when I select the dropdown, it doesnt pass the selected value, what can I do to fix the problem??

Any suggestions??

Comment: Use Flask-WTForms. Object oriented python forms. Lovely jubbly

Comment: did you try `request.form.get('userinput', None)` instead of `request.args.get("userinput")`?

Comment: You need to add a `name` to the dropdown value.

Comment: Can u explain in a bit more detail what u mean by name in drop down ?? @roga

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax from jQuery.

Make the call to the route `/` passing the information you want or doing only a GET and then paint it with jQuery in html.

Here is an example:

https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Flask/Python_Flask_with_AJAX_JQuery.php